# C# Process.Start для pdf файла возвращет false

Tags: c#, .net

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, имеется код для запуска для редактирования того или иного файла, все работает, однако есть проблема с pdf файлом. При вызове метода Process.Start файл открывается, но метод возвращает false почему-то. Проблема наблюдается только с pdf файлами. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

```
var currentProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        UseShellExecute = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = fileWatch.FilePath,
    }
};
```

Comment: какой именно метод возвращает false? Process.Sart возвращает System.Diagnostics.Process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы бы указали, какую именно перегрузку [Process.Start](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start) использовали. Судя по вопросу, ту, которая возвращает `bool`.

Цитата из документации:

> Возвращаемое значение
>
> Boolean
>
> Значение true, если ресурс процесса запущен; значение false, если
>   новый ресурс процесса не был запущен (например, при повторном
>   использовании существующего процесса).

Следовательно, процесс используется повторно.